# How to link 2 tables in asp net?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to connect 2 tables, so that when I receive an object, the completed comments field is returned, and not empty

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne<Article>(s => s.Article)
            .WithMany(g => g.Comments)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.ArticleId);
```

Asp.net Core 3.0 and Postgress in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is What I understand from ur question.
u are querying articles from db and comments are empty
if yes then

u have to [include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) comments in query like this.

```
await DbContext.Articles.Include(article=>article.Commnets).ToArrayAsync()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what you need. But can it be done so that it is immediately issued with comments?

Comment: Please describe it again.. I did not understand.

Comment: As far as I understand this code needs to be written in a method. I can write something to immediately get an article with comments